# Schedule C 1040: How to list expenses related to payments to foreign companies/remote workers?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, sole-proprietorship

Where should I enter foreign independent contractors' payments/expenses (remote work so no 1099) in my schedule C form? Should I list it under "Legal/Professional Fees" or should I put it under Contract Labor even though there is no 1099?

Comment: Why would 1099 matter to classification of your expense?

Comment: I don't know? Should I put it under Contract Labor then? Although these workers/companies are foreign?

Comment: See no reason why not

Answer (score 1):

The 1099 requirement doesn't affect *how* your business expenses are characterized. If you're not required to send 1099 to your contractors - it doesn't make them any less contractors.